# Should I create 2 unit tests for this specific method? Spring MVC app

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit

Here's the method code:

```
@RequestMapping("/employee/{id}")
public String showSpecificEmployee(@PathVariable String id, 
@RequestParam(name = "date", required = false) String date, Model model){

    if(date == null)
        date = YearMonth.now().toString();

    model.addAttribute("employee", employeeService.findEmployeeWithFilteredWorkdaysAndPayments(new Long(id), date));

    return "specificEmployee";
}
```

So far I've created a test:

```
@Test
public void showSpecificEmployee() throws Exception {

    //given
    Employee employee = new Employee();

    //when
    when(employeeService.findEmployeeWithFilteredWorkdaysAndPayments(anyLong(), anyString())).thenReturn(employee);

    //then
    mockMvc.perform(get("/employee/1"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("specificEmployee"))
            .andExpect(model().attributeExists("employee"));

    verify(employeeService, times(1)).findEmployeeWithFilteredWorkdaysAndPayments(anyLong(), anyString());
}
```

Is this fine? Or should I write another one to check whether the `date` is created properly? Any other advices much appreciated.

Comment: yes you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should create 2 test case. 
One case is for not null date, and another case is for null date. 
If you check your test coverage with jacoco or something, you can see what's different between two cases visually.